# wordpress url structure help using sub menu items

Tags: wordpress

I am having an issue with WordPress URL structure. This is something I don't know how to do that. Tried to google but can't find a relevant answer.

My url is domainname/parent/submenu
I cant get this menu structure until and unless I add submenu item link to menu structure, and I dont want that submenu to show up in menu structure to users.

Is there anyway I can get domainname/parent/submenu without showing submenu in the main menu structure?

Make sense?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here, but the only way to change the WordPress URL structure is in the permalink settings. Have you tried editing the permalink settings?

Comment: Yes, That's the only way I know. Isn't there any option so that we can put them in the menu structure and disable those links so that they dont show up in the menu but URL structure is correct? For breadcrumbs reason too

Comment: Are you saying you want a page that doesn't show up in the menu? Couldn't you just create a new menu and not add those pages to it?